# WSO2 - Remove XMLNS from SOAP service

Tags: wcf, soap, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I´ve a WCF SOAP service published on my WSO2, that generates the following response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <op_TestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <op_TestResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.DTO.ResultSet" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Test_ResultSet>
                <a:ID>201704</a:ID>
                <a:Name>Sean Smith</a:Name>
                <a:Phone>555-8745</a:Phone>
            <a:Test_ResultSet>   
        <op_TestResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.DTO.ResultSet" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <op_TestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:Body>
```

There is any way to apply some global configuration on WS2O, in order to remove these namespaces (XMLNS) from all my published SOAPs?

I´ve many services already published on there and would be awesome if I could apply this config once, for all of them.

This´s what I expect.

```
<Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <op_TestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <op_TestResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.DTO.ResultSet" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Test_ResultSet>
                <ID>201704</ID>
                <Name>Sean Smith</Name>
                <Phone>555-8745</Phone>
            <Test_ResultSet>   
        <op_TestResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.DTO.ResultSet" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <op_TestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Body>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

Comment: your response xml it´s malformed

Comment: It´s an example